# Core Plot: Align both y-axes to have the same zero-point

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I have a second `y`-axis (`y2`) in my Core Plot project which I have set up as described in the code below.

How can I get both `y`-axes to have the same zero-point? Currently, the zero-point of each axis is at different heights (in the screen shot below, the `y`-axis' zero-point equals the `y2`-value of 8.8%). How can I get Core Plot to plot the zero-point at the same height for both axes?

My code:

```
CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(xAxisStart);
y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromInt(1);
y.majorTickLength = 5;
y.minorTickLength = 0;
y.majorGridLineStyle = axisLineStyle;

CPTXYPlotSpace *relativePlotSpace = [[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init];
[graph addPlotSpace:relativePlotSpace];
       
CPTXYAxis *y2 = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
y2.axisLineStyle                = axisLineStyle;
y2.coordinate                   = CPTCoordinateY;
y2.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal  = CPTDecimalFromDouble(xAxisLength);
y2.plotSpace                    = relativePlotSpace;
y2.separateLayers               = NO;
y2.majorTickLineStyle           = axisLineStyle;
y2.minorTicksPerInterval        = 1;
y2.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks  = 8;
y2.labelingPolicy               = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions;
graph.axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, y2, nil];
```

[image]

## Edit

Based on Eric's answer below I have added the following code snippet to calculate the range for the y2-axis which should align its zero-point to the y-axis's zero-point:

```
double yAxisAbsoluteLength = 
   ABS(plotSpace.yRange.lengthDouble);
double y2AxisAbsoluteLength = 
   (ABS(relativePlotSpace.yRange.lengthDouble) +
   ABS(relativePlotSpace.yRange.locationDouble));
double yAxisZeroPointToLengthRatio = 
   plotSpace.yRange.locationDouble / 
   yAxisAbsoluteLength;
double y2AxisLocation = yAxisZeroPointToLengthRatio
    *y2AxisAbsoluteLength;
relativePlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange
   plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(y2AxisLocation)
   length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(y2AxisAbsoluteLength)];
```

This seems to work fine if `y`-values are `> 0`. However, for `y`-values `< 0`, the `y2` location is dragged also below the zero-point, which leads to the problem that the calculated `y2AxisAbsoluteLength` value is no longer sufficient to compensate for the dragging of the `y2` location below the zero-point (`y2` points with a high values are cut off or not plotted in the chart). My solution would be simply to add the absolute value of the `y2` location to the `y2AxisAbsoluteLength` value, but this would distort the alignment of the two zero points (`y` and `y2`).

How would I need to change my calculation to account correctly for positive and negative `y`-values?
In this situation, I can't use `expandRangeByFactor` because the multiplication factor is unknown at the time of coding.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both axes stretch the full height of the plot area, so you can calculate some ratios to determine a range for the second axis.

**Example:**

Plot range 1: location -100, length 400

This means the zero-point is at a point 25% (100/400) of the length from the range location. If for the second plot range to have a length of 20, you would give it a location of -5, putting 25% of the length below the zero-point.

Comment: Eric, thank you for your answer. I have changed my code based on your suggestion (please refer to my edited question above). Do you have any suggestion on how I might improve the code to account for the situation in which the y2-values are smaller than the manually calculated y2-location point? Thank you!!

Comment: Correction: `yAxisAbsoluteLength = ABS(plotSpace.yRange.lengthDouble);` If the resulting y2 range is too small to fit the data, use the `-expandRangeByFactor:` method to expand it.

Comment: Eric, thank you for your correction, which I have added to my code in the question above. However, I still have issues for `y`-values as described above. Do you have any idea on how to improve the calculation? I believe I can't use `expandRangeByFactor:` here because the factor required to compensate for the lower `y2` location is not known in advance.